# Asserting view with Grails Spock Unit Test for Controllers

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

- Grails 2.2.4
- Spock 0.7

I'm trying to test that the correct view is rendered from a grails controller. My create method looks like this:

```
def create() {
    def documentCategories = DocumentCategory.list()
    def documentTypes = DocumentType.list()
    def documentComponents = DocumentComponent.list()
    [documentCategories: documentCategories,
        documentTypes: documentTypes,
        documentComponents:documentComponents]
}
```

And my test:

```
def "test create action"() {
    given:
    def model = controller.create()

    expect:
    response.status == 200
    model.documentCategories.size() == 0
    model.view == '/document/create'
}
```

I've tried various versions of `model.view` including:

```
view == '/document/create'
response.forwardedUrl == '/document/create'
```

all of which fail because `model.view`, `view`, and `response.forwardedUrl` are all null.  Suggestions?

Comment: Bump! Did you ever solve it? I'm in a similar situation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are not defining the view explicitly in the controller method then the Grails conventions will take place. Accordingly to documentation a view matching the name of the controller and method will be chosen --> view: "controllerName/methodName"

Regarding your problem, you should not be testing that the Grails framework is working. You should be testing that your controller behaves as you want.

In this case you want to test that your controller does not specify the view as that is the expected behavior of your controller.

Test for this would be:

```
   then:
    controller.modelAndView == null
    response.redirectedUrl == null
```

As the modelAndView will be created if you would call the 'render(view: xxx)' in your controller.

Calling redirect() or chain() in your controller results to response.redirectedUrl to be populated in your unit test

Answer (score 1):

```
view.endsWith('/document/create')
```

should work provided `view` and `model` is explicitly rendered from the `controller`.

```
//controller
render view: 'create', model: [documentCategories: documentCategories,
                               documentTypes: documentTypes,
                               documentComponents:documentComponents]
```

In case of JUnit tests the explicit mention of `view` and `model` is optional, but for Spock spec it is required.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly render a view.  So this will not work for me.

Comment: @Gregg In that case, I fear you need to fallback to JUnit tests which fits appropriately to your need for this particular test.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your test as specified in the 
[Grails Test docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#unitTestingControllers)

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
@TestFor(MyController)
```